# Power supply: How to diferentiate current source and voltage source

Tags: power-supply, voltage, current-source

I found a power supply in my workshop that is marked as 12v@2A it is the typical Chinese power supply to drive leds so it is supposed to be Current Source, but I'm not sure at all, so I would like to know if there is any simple test I can do on the power supply unit to determine if it is a constant current source or a voltage source.

[image: Side view]
[image: Connector view]
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: With the "12V 2A" sticker it's most certainly not a constant current source, but a constant voltage source that can deliver up to 2A.

Comment: I think the Vo ADJ might be a clue

Comment: Also, you know what "constant current" means, right?

Comment: No test needed, there are V- and V+ outputs, there's a Vo adjust trimmer. DC output says: 12 V, 2A. If it was a current source type LED driver it would not state 12 V as the output voltage but a certain range like 10 - 15 V. **So it's a 12 V Constant Voltage supply**

Comment: It means that no matter what load you attach, the current will be constant. So attach two different loads, and observer current.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, @MarcusMüller i know what "constant current" means, i'm not a power electronics especialist (because of that i'm asking) but i know some things :)

Comment: @SubniC excuse my frankness: But if you know what constant current means, the test for that is obvious, see my last comment.

Comment: @MarcusMüller don't worry, i know the theory, but i'm kind of afraid about connecting "loads", i feel like i'm going to get on fire, anyway i may need to be breaver next time. Thanks.

Comment: Fire? From a 12V supply powering some 100 Ohm or more load? This doesn't sound like you're overly concerned with theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be a fixed voltage power supply.  12Volts at up to 2A.  It has a potentiometer marked "Vo Adjust" which would be "output voltage adjust" which would be a useful thing on a constant voltage supply

It does not appear to be a constant current supply.  A constant current supply would have a voltage range rating (say, for example, 5V-20V) and a current rating.  This has a single voltage rating (12V) and a single current rating which is typical for fixed voltage supplies.

Answer (score 1):

How to diferentiate current source and voltage source

The answer is very simple

1-voltage source
[image]

Ideal voltage source have a small internal resistance i.e. 
The voltage does not change when the load change
It gives a constant voltage no matter what is the load

2-current source 
Physically does not existed 
But in theory current source provides a constant current, as long as the load connected to the source terminals has sufficiently low impedance

An ideal current source has an infinite output impedance in parallel with the source. A real-world current source has a very high, but finite output impedance

For more information see the link below

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_source